# Multiple map file in one activity for maps forge 0.3.1 Snapshot

Tags: java, android, mapsforge

I would like to have the possibility to display in one activity multiple map files.
If a use  this.mapView.setMapFile(MAP_FILE);  i can display only one file.

I know there's a way to display more files but i don't know how to do it.